# Implementation and Testing of Exponential Search for scenario where we search the same array/list many times

Tags: python, python-3.x, search, binary-search

[Exponential Search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_search) is an optimization over binary search.

Conceptually, when searching for a number `target` in a list of numbers `nums`, exponential search first finds into which power-of-two sized bucket `nums[2**p: 2**(p+1)]` the `target` falls into. E.g., if `nums` has a size of `30`, then the buckets are `nums[0:1]`, `nums[1:2]`, `nums[2:4]`, `nums[4:8]`, `nums[8:16]`, and `nums[16:30]`. After finding an appropriate bucket, say `nums[lo:hi]`, then we do a standard binary search for `target`, but we limit our scope of search to just `nums[lo:hi]`.

Here's my implementation of Exponential Search for a scenario where we want to search multiple/many targets within the same list of numbers:

```py
from bisect import bisect_left, bisect_right

INF = float('inf')

class ExpSearch:
    def __init__(self, nums, max_target=None):
        self.N = len(nums)
        self.nums = nums
        self.max_target = INF if max_target is None else max_target
        self.pows = []
        self.part = []
        i = 1
        while i < self.N and nums[i] <= self.max_target:
            self.pows.append(i)
            self.part.append(nums[i])
            i <<= 1
        # (i == 1 and self.N <= 1 or nums[1] > self.max_target) or
        #   (i//2 < self.N and self.part[-1] == nums[i//2] <= self.max_target)
        # i >= self.N or nums[i] > self.max_target
        if i < self.N:
            self.pows.append(i)
            self.part.append(nums[i])
        self.P = len(self.part) # == len(self.pows)
        self.pows.append(self.N) # Force self.pows(self.P) == self.N
        self.pows.append(0) # Force self.pows[-1] == 0
        # (i >= self.N and self.part[-1] == nums[1 << (self.P - 1)] <= self.max_target) or
        #   (i < self.N and self.part[-1] == nums[1 << (self.P - 1)] > self.max_target)

    def find_left(self, target, lo=0, hi=None):
        assert target <= self.max_target
        hi = self.N if hi is None else hi
        p = bisect_left(self.part, target)
        # self.part[:p] < target
        # self.part[p:] >= target
        # p == 0 or self.part[p-1] == self.nums[1 << (p-1)] < target
        # p == self.P or self.part[p] == self.nums[1 << p] >= target
        
        # lo = max(lo, 1 << (p-1) if p > 0 else 0)
        # hi = min(hi, 1 << p if p < self.P else self.N)

        lo = max(lo, self.pows[p-1])
        hi = min(hi, self.pows[p])
        return bisect_left(self.nums, target, lo, hi)

    def find_right(self, target, lo=0, hi=None):
        assert target <= self.max_target
        hi = self.N if hi is None else hi
        p = bisect_right(self.part, target)
        # self.part[:p] <= target
        # self.part[:p] > target
        # p == 0 or self.part[p-1] == self.nums[1 << (p-1)] <= target
        # p == self.P or self.part[p] == self.nums[1 << p] > target
        
        # lo = max(lo, 1 << (p-1) if p > 0 else 0)
        # hi = min(hi, 1 << p if p < self.P else self.N)
        
        lo = max(lo, self.pows[p-1])
        hi = min(hi, self.pows[p])
        return bisect_right(self.nums, target, lo, hi)
```

Here's the code with fewer comments:

```
from bisect import bisect_left, bisect_right

INF = float('inf')

class ExpSearch:
    def __init__(self, nums, max_target=None):
        self.N = len(nums)
        self.nums = nums
        self.max_target = INF if max_target is None else max_target
        self.pows = []
        self.part = []
        i = 1
        while i < self.N and nums[i] <= self.max_target:
            self.pows.append(i)
            self.part.append(nums[i])
            i <<= 1
        if i < self.N:
            self.pows.append(i)
            self.part.append(nums[i])
        self.P = len(self.part) # == len(self.pows)
        self.pows.append(self.N) # Force self.pows(self.P) == self.N
        self.pows.append(0) # Force self.pows[-1] == 0

    def find_left(self, target, lo=0, hi=None):
        assert target <= self.max_target
        hi = self.N if hi is None else hi
        p = bisect_left(self.part, target)
        lo = max(lo, self.pows[p-1])
        hi = min(hi, self.pows[p])
        return bisect_left(self.nums, target, lo, hi)

    def find_right(self, target, lo=0, hi=None):
        assert target <= self.max_target
        hi = self.N if hi is None else hi
        p = bisect_right(self.part, target)
        lo = max(lo, self.pows[p-1])
        hi = min(hi, self.pows[p])
        return bisect_right(self.nums, target, lo, hi)
```

1. Any suggestions/improvements are welcome!
2. Can you think of a better name for `self.part`?
3. I use `self.pows == [1 << p for p in range(self.P)]` so that instead of doing `1 << p`, I can just do `self.pows[p]`. Actually, `self.pows == [1 << p for p in range(self.P)] + [self.N, 0]`. The `[self.N, 0]` tail simplifies the `lo = max(lo, ...)` and `hi = min(hi, ...)` code.
4. A lot of the code is invariants (conditions that hold at that point of execution) as comments. Is there a better way to convey these invariants/conditions?

---

I also wrote some test code. My main priority is to get a code review on the implementation, but I would be glad to hear suggestions/comments about the test code as well.

```py
from random import randint
from .expsearch import ExpSearch

N = 1_000 # 100_000
MIN = -10_000
MAX = 10_000
T = 100

def gen_nums(N, min_, max_):
    return [randint(min_, max_) for _ in range(N)]

def test():
    nums = gen_nums(N, MIN, MAX)
    nums.sort()
    ES = ExpSearch(nums)
    for _ in range(T):
        target = randint(MIN-0.1*abs(MIN), MAX+0.1*abs(MAX))
        l = ES.find_left(target)
        # assert all(num < target for num in nums[:l])
        # assert all(num >= target for num in nums[l:])
        assert l == 0 or nums[l-1] < target
        assert l == N or nums[l] >= target

        r = ES.find_right(target)
        # assert all(num <= target for num in nums[:r])
        # assert all(num > target for num in nums[r:])
        assert r == 0 or nums[r-1] <= target
        assert r == N or nums[r] > target
        
        print(f"Passed with target = {target}")
```

The test code generates a sorted list of size `N` whose values lie within `[MIN, MAX] == [-10_000, 10_000]` inclusive. Then it runs `T = 100` tests. In each test, a random target is generated. The random target is:

- within `[MIN, MAX]` with chance greater than 80%,
- below MIN with a >8% chance, and
- above MAX with a >8% chance.

Then the test tries to find `target` within `nums` using both `ExpSearch.find_left` and `ExpSearch.find_right`. In each case, the test checks that the returned index is correct.

I ran the tests with two `N`'s.

- `N = 1_000` produces a sparse `nums` since `N == 1_000 << MAX - MIN == 20_000`. It is unlikely that the generated `nums` has a lot of duplicates.
- `N = 100_000` produces a dense `nums` since `N == 100_000 >> MAX - MIN == 20_000`. It is guaranteed that the generated `nums` has duplicates (in fact, it has at least `80_000` duplicates).

All tests pass.

Comment: Please don't modify your code after receiving answers. This potentially invalidates the answer(s) and is overall confusing for everyone reading this Q & A later. If you have a new version with major improvements, feel free to ask a new, follow up question instead.

Comment: My review is short as it is because I am looking forward to a (cross-linked) follow-on question with signatures like `find_left(self, target, start, offset=0, shift=1):`, offset 0 meaning *figure out direction yourself*, >0 up (and don't bother to look at start), <0 down. And shift is the modification to the skip length.

Comment: @greybeard Not sure I'm understanding. What direction are you referring to? `offset > 0` indicates that `nums` is sorted in ascending order? Also not sure what is meant by "modification of the skip length".

Comment: You coded one of the modifications mentioned by en.wikipedia, [Bentley&Yao](https://www.slac.stanford.edu/pubs/slacpubs/1500/slac-pub-1679.pdf) *Algorithm B_1 (Binary Search)*, who didn't do more to name any of the algorithms. Just as *linear search* refers (at least conceptually) to index values increasing by one, I'd use *exponential search* for a base *b* to increasing powers - what they call *the gambler's strategy*. (Base 2^k is convenient where a binary search is to follow.)

Comment: You hyperlinked this code representation from [a question about 2SUM](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/152188/is-the-complexity-of-this-two-sum-binary-search-algorithm-o-lg-n-or-o-lg?noredirect=1#comment320298_152188). In that scenario, not only is the promising index to start looking for a complement 0 at most once, but the direction alters between hi&lo. And it is known that the starting index does not indicate the target.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but Bentley&Yao's *Algorithm* B1 seems to be the same as the *Exponential Search* algorithm. In page 5 of that paper, they say they find `m` such that

*"2^(m-1) <= n <= 2^m - 1"*

The `bound` found in [Exponential Search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_search) corresponds to `m` as follows:

`lo = bound / 2 == 2**(m-1) == self.pows[m-1]` and `hi = bound == 2**m == self.pows[m]`.

I don't see an implementation of Algorithm B1 in Bentley&Yao's paper -- I just see a description of how `m` relates to the target `n`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(Exponential Search is an improvement over binary search
*where the target can be expected to be close to some starting point*.)

- `class ExpSearch` does not have a [documented purpose](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/#what-is-a-docstring) and scope of application.
  Same applies to `find_left()` and `find_right()`
- using binary search on the pre-determined "partition values" it *does not implement exponential search*:
  The probing sequence is much different.
  It should be conventional using part.index(target), instead - ***if*** lo was 0:
- if `lo` != 0, the values in `part` aren't helpful in finding bounds for binary search
- I think the "invariant comments" great.
- The test doesn't exercise setting `no` and `hi`

Minor:
• `P` isn't really used
• using `__init__(self, nums, max_target=INF)` allows `self.max_target = max_target`

It would be great if the test compared measures of effort for binary & exponential search for uniform, binomial and exponential distribution.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! Making changes now.

Comment: I would argue that doing binary search on the precomputed partition values (i.e. `p = bisect_left(self.part, target)`) is just a different way of doing standard Exponential Search's first step:

```
bound = 1
while bound < self.N and self.nums[bound] < target:
    bound <<= 1
```

and it's a more efficient way of doing the first step of Exponential Search when we're going to Exponential Search the same list many times.

Indeed, I added the above `bound = 1 ... ` snippet + `assert bound == 1 << p` to each of `find_left` and `find_right`, reran the tests, and got no assertion errors.

Comment: Was advised not to make changes to OP code, but I am updating locally with the suggestions.